# Selected node value in ASP.NET TreeView

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, treeview

I am using VB.NET code where I bind nodes to build a TreeView dynamically. Every node is added using the node click event below.

My problem is that `thisFileNode.Value` returns the URL value, but when I attempt to get it through `JavaScript` some values are missing in the URL. For example, when the actual value is:

`\\111.111.1.211\Daily\Admin\Resources\btn9.jpg`

, the retrieved value is, in fact:

`\111.111.1.211DailyAdminResourcesbtn9.jpg`

, while the letter `b` in `btn9` is changing to a square. I am using the following code:

```
thisFileNode.NavigateUrl = "javascript:clickNode(this, '" + thisFileNode.Value + "');"
```

where clickNode is:

```
function clickNode(sender, id){
   alert(id); 
}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: sorry to bother you all... i have got the solution for this :)

Comment: looks like, segments of your uri are concatenated. how do you know thisFileNode.Value is ..\Daily\Admin\Res... ? double check it. either your db has that wrong url or u are making it that way.

Comment: You should post your solution.